# How do I do a bilinear interpolation in a data frame of (602x5) in python

Tags: python, dataframe, interpolation

**I wanted to do a Bilinear interpolation** in a data frame of size (602x5).
How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

[So, here attached is the image of the data frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMC3U.png)

I wanted to find for any value of index lying in between those value of Indexes it should give me a interpolated value corresponding to a value lying in between those columns.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list `data` containing some values, you may interpolate using this:

```
from math import floor, ceil

def interpolate( data, pos ) :
    a = data[floor( pos )]
    b = data[ceil( pos )]
    return a + (b-a) * (pos - floor(pos))
```

Your columns seems to be unrelated to each other, so there's no need for bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Hi Lenik,
I think it would require a bilinear interpolation as first we need to interpolate between the indexes and then between the colums and fetch out the value from the corresponding cell
For ex: if I have y = -1.185(lying between indexes -1.1879 and -1.183) , x = 0.233(lying between column 0.01 and 0.25) then it would require a bilinear interpolation to return a value correspondingly (from the values in pink and purple)

Isn't it?

Comment: using floor and ceil you will always get the same integral values. for my case in the indexes column I would always get -1 and -2 as ceil and floor which would reduce the accuracy of the values that I am supposed to get through bilinear interpolation

Comment: i assumed you have a data frame with integer indices, and would like to interpolate between those. once you start working with floating numbers, there would be no need to round up or down.

Comment: Right, so can you help me with this now?